# Error: unexpected '='

Tags: r

I have a table in which I wanted to delete rows that have 'NA' in one of the columns and end up with a new dataset that would contain only rows that had numeric input (in my case greater than zero). I used *dplyr* package. My initial code was:

```
newdataset<-filter(dataset, columnName !== NA)
```

This gave me the following error:

> unexpected '=' in "newdataset<-filter(dataset, columnName !=="

I eventually achieved the task by: 
`newdataset<-filter(dataset, columnName >=0)`. 
But could you please point me to the error in my first code? Thanks.

Comment: `!=` instead may work.

Comment: Note that `!(columname==NA)` is equivalent to `columnname != NA` but **neither of these** does what you want. Instead, look at the `is.na` function. Equality comparisons with `NA` are not valid in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is.na` is recommended for testing `NA`-ness.

```
newdataset<-filter(dataset, !is.na(columnName))
```

As comments and other answers point out, `!==` isn't valid syntax, you want `!=`. But for testing `NA`-ness, `is.na` is generally better because it will return FALSE on NA rather than NA on NA.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- 1:4
x !== 2
Error: unexpected '=' in "x !=="
x != 2
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```